# Plesk: health monitoring thresholds per core or total?

Tags: monitoring, plesk

plesk has a built-in health monitoring which lets you configure alarm thresholds for automatic notification. most of these thresholds are percentage-based to flag a notification if memory or cpu usage gets too high.

i'm having trouble determining how these percentages are measured. measuring for memory is easy (we're dealing with a fixed figure here) but cpu usage is more complicated on multi-proc servers.

```
CPU Info: 
Architecture: x86_64
CPU op-mode(s): 32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order: Little Endian
CPU(s): 8
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-7
Thread(s) per core: 2
Core(s) per socket: 4
Socket(s): 1
NUMA node(s): 1
Vendor ID: GenuineIntel
CPU family: 6
Model: 42
Stepping: 7
CPU MHz: 1600.000
BogoMIPS: 6784.52
Virtualization: VT-x
L1d cache: 32K
L1i cache: 32K
L2 cache: 256K
L3 cache: 8192K
NUMA node0 CPU(s): 0-7
```

Now am i right in thinking, that if a single core hits the 90% then this would trigger the Alarm on the Health Monitoring?

Most of my Flags are from 80% = Yellow to 90% = Red
And its pretty much always on Red, I believe this is because its Multi Core and the health tool is working on a single core.

if i use the command TOP with Shift and I 
Then i get the overall CPU process, and its nothing along the lines as to what the health monitor is showing me the total % is.

I dont know if i have picked up false information or been miss guided, But maybe someone can help steer me in the right direction, or shine a little light on it at least

:)

Thanks

[image: Top on Single]
[image: Top CPU Total]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After alot of posts, Troubleshooting and pestering, i finally found the answer. 
In Short, YES Plesk Health Monitoring does not really account for any core >1

So in my case 6 cores, When Core 6, Flicks to 80% for 1 second, The alarm is triggered. 
But when you work on a Average, the CPU does not hit 12%

I asked this, over in the official Plesk Forum, and failed to get a response. 
Many Serve companys and partners of Plesk, One did respond and say its a known issue that causes alot of headacks

You can increase your Load Average, from 1 minute to 15, This will reduce the alerts alot, Or well in my case it has.

1 Minute with CPU hitting 80% = Alarm

15 Minutes, CPU hits 80% for 30 seconds, Its average on the 15 minutes is 20% = No Alarm :)